# PHP comparing a list of letters to an array of words

Tags: php

I'm trying to make it so I can take a list of letters, `$rack`, imported from the form and compare it to the array `$words`, which is the dictionary imported from a text file.  I then want to build an array, `$playable`, that will store all of the words that contain any of the letters in `$rack`.

This is what I have

```
<?php

session_start();
$rack = $_GET["letters"]; // list of letters imported from form

$words = array();  // imported text file with the list of playable words

$playable = array(); // array created by finding playable words from dictionary


//populates $words with the text file dictionary.txt
$filename = 'dictionary2.txt';

$fp = @fopen($filename, 'r'); 

$words = fread($fp); 


// array to score word

$score = array("a" => 1, "b" => 1, "c" => 1, "d" => 1, "e" => 1, "f" => 1, "g" => 1, "h" => 1, 
"i" => 1, "j" => 1, "k" => 1, "l" => 1, "m" => 1, "n" => 1, "o" => 1, "p" => 1, "q" => 1, 
"r" => 1, "s" => 1, "t" => 1, "u" => 1, "v" => 1, "w" => 1, "x" => 1, "y" => 1, "z" => 1); 

// loop that checks each index, or words, against the list of letters the player
// informs us he has while building the second array.

for ( $i=0; $i<sizeof($words); $i++){  
    if (in_array($rack, $words[$i])){
        $playable[] = $words[$i];
        }
}


?>
<html>

<title>Hanging With Friends Help</title>

<body style="background-color:black;">
<font color = "white">
<center><img src="wordslogo.jpg" alt="Cheater!" /> </center>
<form name="input" action="http://i211.soic.indiana.edu/~kmnacke/hangingwithfriends.php" method="get">


    <p>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <center><input type="text" name="letters" /></center>

    </p>
    <center><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></center>

    <center><label>

    <?php 


 //prints the list of playable words

    for ( $i=0; $i<sizeof($playable); $i++){  
        echo $playable[$i];

}

    for ( $i=0; $i<sizeof($words); $i++){  
            echo $words[$i];

    }


    ?>


    </label></center>


    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: so what is your question? what problems are you facing with?

Comment: Do you actually mean to get words that contain ALL the letters in the `$rack` ? Like in scrabble to see what words from the dictionary I can make with my set letters?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `in_array` ever, it should be removed from PHP... very, very slow. Use `array_flip` combined with `isset`, which is several orders of magnitude faster.

Here is the code you wanted, it also adds up the score for each word based on the score you have assigned for each letter.

```
$words = 'these are the words';
$words = explode(' ',$words);

$rack = 'a b c d e f g';
$rack = explode(' ',$rack);
$rack = array_flip($rack);

$score = array("a" => 1, "b" => 1, "c" => 1, "d" => 1, "e" => 1, "f" => 1, "g" => 1, "h" => 1, 
"i" => 1, "j" => 1, "k" => 1, "l" => 1, "m" => 1, "n" => 1, "o" => 1, "p" => 1, "q" => 1, 
"r" => 1, "s" => 1, "t" => 1, "u" => 1, "v" => 1, "w" => 1, "x" => 1, "y" => 1, "z" => 1); 

$playable = array();
$playable_score = array();

foreach($words as $val)
{
$len = strlen($val);
$thisscore = 0;
for($run=0; $run<$len; $run++)
    {
    if (isset($rack[$val[$run]]]) && isset($score[$val[$run]]))
    $thisscore+=$score[$val[$run]];
    }
if ($thisscore>0)
    {
    $playable[]=$val;
    $playable_score[]=$thisscore;
    }
}
```

Also note that you can just get rid of the `$rack` and use `$score` assuming that you are always counting all letters. In this case you can just give some letters a value of 0. To make this change, just modify this line `if (isset($rack[$val[$run]]) && isset($score[$rack[$val[$run]]))` to this `if (isset($score[$rack[$val[$run]]))` and remove the initialization of `$rack`.

Comment: There were some syntax errors, and I BELIEVE `$score[$rack[$val[$run]]]` should just be `$score[$val[$run]]` Also: $rack is based on user input, and let's assume that you can have two of the same letter. Won't array_flip get rid of the duplicates, overwriting keys? Is my solution completely overkill and slow? Here's a link to your code, working on codepad. http://codepad.org/9EQY16gO

Comment: Fixed the syntax error. Array_flip gets rid of duplicates but you are only checking for the existence of the letter so you don't want duplicates. I have done what was explained in the question. `strpos` is not overkill, but it will be 10,000 times slower than this.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing which one you actually want - Here is how I would do both:

Does anybody have a faster way to do this? (I'm here to learn!)

Here is a codepad link: http://codepad.org/nTE8QWkf

```
<?php
$str = '
what
are
you
doing';

$dict_arr = explode("\n", $str);
$rack_arr = str_split('what')


?>
<pre>
<?php print_r(findwordswithany($dict_arr, $rack_arr)); ?>
</pre>
<pre>
<?php print_r(findwordswithall($dict_arr, $rack_arr));?>
</pre>
<?php


function findwordswithany($dict_arr, $rack_arr){
            $working_arr = $rack_arr;
    $found_arr = array();
    foreach($dict_arr as $word){    
        foreach($working_arr as $key => $letter){
            if(strpos($word, $letter) !== false){               
                $found_arr[] = $word;
               //Modified to remove the letter from further 
               unset($working_arr[$key]);
                break 1;
            }
        }
                    $working_arr = $rack_arr;   
    }
    if(count($found_arr) > 0)
        return $found_arr;
    else
        return false;
}

function findwordswithall($dict_arr, $rack_arr){
    $found_arr = array();
    foreach($dict_arr as $word){    
        $foundall = true;
        foreach($rack_arr as $letter){
            if(strpos($word, $letter) === false){               
                $foundall = false;
                break 1;
            }
        }
        if($foundall === true){
        $found_arr[] = $word;
        }
    }
    if(count($found_arr) > 0)
        return $found_arr;
    else
        return false;
}
?>
```

Comment: This is what I need.  I'm trying to make a scrabble teacher where it will take the list of letters that you have and tell you which words are playable.  I wasn't going to include the board in the play because I figured that would be too hard to do.  Thank you very much!!

Comment: Yeah that would be hard to do; to include the letters that are already played on the board - and make it accurate anyways.You'd have to figure in the maximum length of the word, before it hits another tile, the direction, etc etc. As @ALasdair stated, his method is probably faster, but right now it only figures in words that have at least 1 letter from the rack. You should accept one of our answers, whichever one helped you the most. Good luck on your assignment!

Comment: Also my function doesn't factor in if the word requires two of the same letter, I will modify it real quick so it will.